# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

OK, the scenario is: i`m trying to keep 3 nested forms on the same controller. The relation between the user and shop is working smoothly the problem arises **between the shop and shop_type.**
So, when i try update the shop_type info in **shop edit view**

Spit out this error: **ShopType(#70233617878800) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70233610891660)**

i searched already about this on api docs but but still a mystery for me why the shop_type is passing as a hash.

thanks.

**ShopsController**

```
def new
   @user = current_user
   @shop = @user.build_shop.shop_type

   end


   def create
     @user = current_user
      @shop = @user.build_shop(params[:shop])
          if  @shop.save   
        flash.now[:success] = "blah"
         render :edit
      else
        render  :new 
    end
  end

   def edit
 @user = current_user
  if @shop = current_user.shop 
   render :edit
  else render :new
   end
 end


   def update   
       @user = current_user
           @shop = current_user.shop
        if @shop.update_attributes(params[:shop])
         flash.now[:success] = "blah"
         render :edit
      else
        render  :edit
    end
  end 
end
```

**ShopModel**

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :shop_type
```

**Shop_typeModel**

```
has_many :shops
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shops 
 attr_accessible :shops, :shop_attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out, still not clear why i have to use **:shop_type_id** instead of just **:shop_type** on fields_for.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `config/development.rb` line:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

I don't know why this error happens but this approach resolves this problem. But you should know that it will cache classes and changes in your rails classes can not give any effect

Comment: interesting, i`ll do this, but for production the cache_classes is set true, in any case thanks man.

Comment: I think you have bug in your params. Could you show what includes params[:shop]? `raise params[:shop].inspect`

Comment: i would man, but the debugger of ruby 1.9.3 is bugged and very painful to install, until they release a stable version i`ll keep trying find what`s going on.